# How to loop through properties in a tab and display them using Razor?

Tags: umbraco

I have a Document Type, that has a tab with some properties.

The properties are Upload types, and Simple Editor types.

(Users are supposed to upload images with some image text).

I have not grouped the "Upload" and "Simple Editor" properties, so how do i do this?

Next question,

I want to loop through each group (there should be 3 currently) and display them on my website.

The markup should look like the following:

```
<div>
 <img src="PATH-TO-UPLOAD-TYPE" />
 <div>"TEXT FROM SIMPLE EDTIOR TYPE"</div>
</div>
..
<div>
 <img src="PATH-TO-UPLOAD-TYPE" />
 <div>"TEXT FROM SIMPLE EDTIOR TYPE"</div>
</div>
...
```

I would like to use Razor for this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, using the Razor model, you can't. The content object that you get on the front end only contains the properties, the tabs are not included, as they're only really for organising things in the back office.

You CAN get that information using the Umbraco API, but it's pretty database intensive and could potentially be quite slow if you have a lot of properties/tabs.

You'd be better grouping them yourself in your Razor Macro.

Answer (score 0):

for the second part, you can acces the properties of a page via `@Model.property`. For example:

```
<div>
  <div>@Model.simpleProperty</div>
</div>
```